# Close worksheet and open another with the same name

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning everyone! I'm going through a problem here at my company, some people copy an official spreadsheet to edit on their desktops. I already managed to make the MsgBox to warn that the copied file is not the official one, after all the official almost every day receives improvements. But I would like to put an option suggesting to open the official file instead of the copy, but I can not make Excel close the first file (copy) and open the second (official), because they have exactly the same name. Is it possible to do this with VBA?

(Translated by Bing Translator)

I tried the following:

```
Application.OnTime Now, "reabrir"
ThisWorkbook.Close True
```

And

```
Sub reabrir()

Dim wb As Workbook
    
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("H:\Projeto de Desenvolvimento de Produtos (PDP)\52 - REUNIÃO DIÁRIA\REUNIÃO DIÁRIA - INDIVIDUAL.xlsm")

End Sub
```

But this does not work, excel opens the same file (unofficial copy).

Comment: In such cases I usually generate a bat-file that the macro runs before closing itself, then the bat-file has a pause for a few seconds to make sure the file is closed before it opens the other file. But is the file getting updates daily because it has new data, or is it the VBA that is updated daily? Because if it's the VBA then you could make that a add-in that you can push updates to the users.

Comment: Also, the reason your code does not work is because when you run reabrir() the code needs to open the copied file to read the code, that means you already have one file open and the workbook.open fails since the copy is already open. So as I said above make sure something else than VBA opens the file such as a bat-file.

Comment: Could have a helper file on the network that gets opened by whatever you have going on now that wants to force this and in the Workbook_Open you close the copy and open the original and after the original is there, close the helper-file (could have this in the original or let it close itself, your choice). It's an "ugly" solution but it would circumvent the issue without having to create the aforementioned bat-file every time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use somthing like this to open the file.
This creates a bat-file in the temp folder and runs it when Excel is closed.

```
    MyFile = Environ("Temp") & "\cmd.bat"
    
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
    ' three seconds delay to make sure the file is closed
    If Application.OperatingSystem = "Windows (32-bit) NT 5.01" Then
        Print #fnum, "ping -n 3 127.0.0.1>nul"
    Else
        Print #fnum, "timeout /T 3 >nul"
    End If
    Print #fnum, "start excel ""H:\Projeto de Desenvolvimento de Produtos (PDP)\52 - REUNIÃO DIÁRIA\REUNIÃO DIÁRIA - INDIVIDUAL.xlsm"""
    Close #fnum
    
    Shell MyFile, vbNormalFocus
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkBook.close
```

This will force Excel to close and because it sets the DisplayAlerts to false then it would be a good idea to make sure your file that is opened has a workbook_open that sets it to true again.

Comment: Note that in lots of corporate environments, it's not allowed to execute a cmd-file from the temp-folder

Comment: Oh really? I thought we had it as bad as it gets at our company. In that case you can (perhaps) just use a folder on the C-drive or on the desktop I guess

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with this command:

```
Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe """ & "H:\Projeto de Desenvolvimento de Produtos (PDP)\52 - REUNIÃO DIÁRIA\REUNIÃO DIÁRIA - INDIVIDUAL.xlsm", vbNormalFocus
ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
```

I don't know if this will work always and correctly for everyone, but so far it's working!